# Crash if end of scrollView reached iOS7 Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table view, the selected cell pushes a `UIView` with `scrollView`.

On iOS7 **only**, if I reach the end of the `scrollView` and go back to `tableView` I get a crash with no error in the debugger.

If I don't scroll **right to the end**,  all works fine. I can scroll to almost just a pixel to the end of the scroll view with no crash,  as soon as I hit the end of the `scrollView`, the crash happens

If I change the size of the scroll view, no matter what size is, as soon as its scrolled to the END I get the crash.

This problem is not evident before iOS 7

error message: `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ICAppDelegate class]));`
  `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address = 0xc)`

Comment: This is from the main.m and what is ICAppDelegate? must be some custom delegate.

Comment: Put some breakpoints in and run it in simulator, that error message is a generic (and very vague one, thanks Apple). You know roughly where it's crashing, so isolate the area with break points. `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually memory out of bounds, so look for array indexing issues.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions.  When it triggers, the stack trace should be more useful.

Comment: Been trying to figure this out with breakpoints, no further forward im going to work around this by scrolling the view up using `contentoffset` if it reaches the bottom

Comment: I have the same problem , did get a solution or know why it crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set `the scrollView datasource` and `delegate` as `nil` before go back to `tableView`